# how to reduce time complexity of given code?

Tags: c

Code to check to check duplicate elements and return true if there a duplicate elements and false if not.

```
bool containsDuplicate(int *a, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int element = a[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if (a[j] == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I thought it is correct code but it is showing a time limit exceeded error.

Comment: Your code has quadratic complexity, as you loop over the array for every element in the array.
A possible optimization would for example involve a Hashmap. Not giving you more tips since that would spoil the code challenge. Good luck!

Comment: hara sahiti vemuru, It is correct code, just very inefficient.

Comment: Because it is working code, this may be a good question to post on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

> to reduce time complexity of given code?

OP's approach is O(n*n)

Below is an O(n*log n) approach.

1. Copy array `a` to a new array `b`
2. Sort `b` with `qsort()`
3. Walk `b` looking for adjacent repeats.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have the memory...

Assuming 4 bytes `int` (which is common) you can do it in O(N) by using half a giga byte dynamic memory. It's done by making an array of unsigned char and let each bit represent an `int` value.

Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int containsDuplicate(int *a, int n)
{
  int res = 0;
  size_t sz = (1ULL << 32) / 8;  // or just (1ULL << (32-3))
  unsigned char* p = calloc(sz, 1);
  if (!p) exit(1);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    unsigned int u = a[i];
    unsigned int idx = u / 8;
    unsigned int bit = u % 8;
    unsigned char v = p[idx];

    if (((v >> bit) & 0x1) != 0)
    {
      res = 1;
      break;
    }
    p[idx] |= (1 << bit);
  }
  free(p);
  return res;
}


int main()
{
  int arr[] = {435435, 7657, 43243, 435435, 989723};
  size_t sz_a = sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0];

  if (containsDuplicate(arr, sz_a))
  {
      puts("Duplicate found");
  }
  else
  {
    puts("No duplicate found");
  }

  arr[3] = 42;

  if (containsDuplicate(arr, sz_a))
  {
      puts("Duplicate found");
  }
  else
  {
    puts("No duplicate found");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Duplicate found
No duplicate found
```

Comment: Nice brute-force approach.  With such attacks, using `unsigned` to house the bit array is usual faster than `unsigned char`, yet your idea is well presented.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Agree... I should probably have used `unsigned` for the "bit array". Not sure why I went for `unsigned char`.

Comment: Simplicity? `unsigned char` width is nicely 8 (`CHAR_BIT`).  `unsigned` has more cases to consider, etc.